# Create histogram from DataFrame (where the index values are the variables)

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, histogram

I have a DataFrame containing the index and its respective values. For instance:

```
       | Count |
ID     
Amy    |   5   |
Chris  |   4   |
Gabe   |   2   |
```

How can I create a histplot from this DataFrame with the index as axis values?

I have done the following but it sets the count of each bar at 1.0:

```
sns.histplot(data=df, y=df.index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A histogram is something you would use to show the distribution of a continuous variable. Since you just want to compare the count values between different categories, a barplot is more appropriate.

```py
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Count', y=df.index)
```

[image: barplot]